# want attachEvent Replacement in win7 IE11

Tags: javascript, attachevent

```
            else {
                oStatus.attachEvent("onmouseover", function(){getCoordinates(oStatus)});
                oStatus.innerHTML="<class='SHOW'>Status: <b>New</b>. Click <a class='customlink' href='javascript:startHere();'><span id='here'>here</span></a> to start.";
                }
```

//I got the error: "Object does not support property or method 'attachEvent'"

Can any one help me for IE11 fixing this issue

Answer (score 1):

Use the DOM standard [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener), just as you would in any other browser. IE has supported it since IE9.

```
element.addEventListener('mouseover', function (event) { });
```